# How to filter fields owned by a foreign-key-referred-model with HQL?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, hql

For example, the model **`Comment`** has fields:

- `content`
- `account` (referred to model **`Account`**)
- `article` (referred to model **`Article`**)

Now if I want to filter the whole `article` field when query, I can define a construction method without `content` for class **`Comment`** like:

```
public Comment(String content, Account account) {
    this.content = content;
    this.account = account;
}
```

And define query:

```
@Query("SELECT NEW Comment(content, account) FROM Comment WHERE channel_id = ?1")
List<Comment> findCommentsByChannel_Id(Long channel_id);
```

But now I also want to filter field `account`'s field `password`, how can I realize that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create [Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) with the attributes you want to keep.